# Firebase onCall request fail on chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I deployed this and tried to call it on my browser using the url given by firebase cmd. Is it possible to call onCall on browser or do I need to call it from a client?

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall((input, context) => {
    // res.status(200).json({results: "Success"})
    console.log("test")
    return { status: 200, message: "Success"}
})
```

Got this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL of a [callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) function cannot be used to directly access it.  A callable function has a [specific protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) used to pass data back and forth.  If the client doesn't implement that protocol, the request won't work.

If you want direct browser access without a special protocol, you should write an [regular HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) using `onRequest` instead of a callable.

Comment: how do i test it then?

Comment: You can test it with something like [postman](https://www.postman.com/) or curl. You need to make a post call with proper headers as the link above suggests.